# Why the eigen function returns "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"?

Tags: r, loops, eigenvalue

I'm using for the question here the classic example of the Lotka-Volterra model with predation (2 ODEs, 6 parameters). I need to calculate the equilibrium point, which I know the analytical expression of, and the eigenvalues of the Jacobian matrix at this point. I need to do this for a big number of locations (here I'll do only 2), which differ in this example by the value of 2 parameters, epsilon and psi (2 parameter values for each for the 2 locations).

I created a loop (because again the size of epsilon and psi is going to be much bigger). Here is my code:

```
A21 = as.matrix(c(0, 0))
alpha = -1
beta = 2
gamma = 1
delta = -2
epsilon = as.matrix(c(0, 1))
psi = as.matrix(c(0, -2))
x = 0
y = 0
param = c(0,0,0,0,0,0)
eig = A21
eqn <- function (t, state, pars)
{
  with (as.list(c(state, pars)),  {
    dx <- x*(alpha - beta*y - epsilon)
    dy <- -y*(gamma - delta*x + psi)
    list(c(dx, dy))
  })
}

for(i in 1:dim(A21)[1]) {
  x[i] = (gamma + psi[i]) / delta
  y[i] = (alpha - epsilon[i]) / beta
  param[i] = c(alpha, beta, gamma, delta, epsilon[i], psi[i])
  eig[i] = eigen(jacobian.full(y = c(x = x[i], y = y[i]), func = eqn, parms = param[i]))$values
}
```

I can calculate inside the equilibrium point (vector x,y), but the function "eigen" returns "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length". I guess it comes from the way I try to replace the list of parameters, I tried different ways (above is one of them) but nothing has worked. Could it be that the double function "eigen(jacobian.full(...))" does not like to be depending on indexes ?

Anybody can help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't test your code, because we don't have the `jacobian.full` function, but I'll guess you mean the one in the `rootSolve` package.   When I run the code after `library(rootsolve)`, I get these warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: In param[i] <- c(alpha, beta, gamma, delta, epsilon[i], psi[i]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In eig[i] <- eigen(jacobian.full(y = c(x = x[i], y = y[i]), func = eqn,  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
3: In param[i] <- c(alpha, beta, gamma, delta, epsilon[i], psi[i]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
4: In eig[i] <- eigen(jacobian.full(y = c(x = x[i], y = y[i]), func = eqn,  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Those aren't coming from the `eigen` function, they're coming from the last two lines of your code.  It's not clear what your intentions are here.  `param` is initialized to be length 6, then you're trying to replace one element of it with a length 6 vector.  Maybe the solution is simply to use

```
param = c(alpha, beta, gamma, delta, epsilon[i], psi[i])
eig = eigen(jacobian.full(y = c(x = x[i], y = y[i]), func = eqn, parms = param))$values
```

but I really can't see what you intend.

Comment: Yes I did use the package "rootSolve" (and also "deSolve" and "matrixcalc"). 

I wanted to create a list of "param" and of eigenvalues for each set of parameter, which is why I marked each of them with the index, but I understand the mistake I was doing. 

Also I noticed that I get the wrong eigenvalues if I write "param = c(alpha, beta, gamma, delta, epsilon[i], psi[i])", while I get them right if I write "param = c(alpha, beta, gamma, delta, epsilon = epsilon[i], psi = psi[i])".

Anyway, thank you so much for your help!